# сравнение структуры таблиц в двух базах на MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql

Необходимо сравнить структуру таблиц в двух базах. Например, база1 по стоянию на 01.02.2011 и база2 - это измененная база1 по состоянию на 01.12.2011. Необходимо найти различия в структуре таблиц. Как это проще сделать с минимальными затратами времени. Таблиц предостаточно, открыл через SSMS - все таблицы в экран не влазят ))

Answer (score 2):

В Visual Studio тоже есть утилита для сравнения БД.

Answer (score 1):

DB Comparer